# Accessing private variable outside its class in java

Tags: java, visibility

The following Java programs compiles successfully.
I am expecting an error in the statement `y.className = "No class name.";`
since the private variable **className** are accessed outside its class.

```
class t { 

    public static void main(String[] r) {

        Y y = new Y();

        y.className = "No class name.";

        y.echoClassName();
    }   

    static class Y { 

        private String className = "Class Name is Y."; 

        public void echoClassName() {

            System.out.println(className);
        }   
    }   
}
```

Why it shows no error?

Comment: @MarounMaroun  Any reference?

Comment: See the docs: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The scope of a private variable is the whole top level class in which it is enclosed, in your case `t`. See for example [JLS #6.6.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.6.1) (emphasis mine):

> Otherwise, the member or constructor is declared private, and access is permitted if and only if it occurs ***within the body of the top level class*** (§7.6) that encloses the declaration of the member or constructor.

Answer (score 1):

Y is a nested class. which means it is embeeded in t class, where you run main. 
It is visible for its class only, but if you nest a class with private variable in class, then you can access this variable in this class.

If you put Y class in another file and create it in t, then you will get error of visibility. 
Since you are using nested class, everything is ok.